# datatables server side response nesting

Tags: ajax, json, datatables, server-side

Simple issue regarding usage of datatables (http://www.datatables.net) and server side data retrieval.
Datatables expects a special format from the server, to be in the root of the response:

```
{
  "sEcho": 1,
  "iTotalRecords": "57",
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": "57",
  "aaData": [
    {
      "engine": "Gecko",
      "browser": "Firefox 1.0",
      "platform": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "version": "1.7",
      "grade": "A"
    },...
  ]
}
```

But I want to nest all of this in another place in my json response from the server:

```
{
  myshit: "",
  status: "success",
  morestuff: "yoyo",
  datatables: { here will be all of the json related to datatables }
}
```

I haven't found a property for this in the API.
The only options I know about, right now, is to define all the columns with the exact nested property they should look for.

Do you know of such a property? or can suggest a good way to achieve this nesting?

Answer (score 0):

Because sAjaxSource expects the dataset in the particular order, you would have to use $.getJSON instead to have the nested layout you described